# Bootstrap collapse function triggers from validation - How to avoid?

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using Bootstrap within a Symfony 2.7 based WebApp. Now I came across a strange problem when using the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) `collapse` function within a `Form`:

The `collapse` function is used to toggle the visibility of DOM objects. If use this function to toggle an element (e.g. a `div` container) within a `Form`, the form validation is triggered.

When I run the my code (see below) on my server, a "This field is required" messages pops up, as soon as a toggle the container using the button.

**This does not seem to work here. The Snippet below works just fine.** However you can see problem when **running the Snippet on w3Schools.com instead**. Click on [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_listgroup) to get to one of their examples. R**eplace the example code with my Snippet and run it.**

The effect is the same es on my server: A click on the toggle button will trigger the form validation.

How can this bee? What is difference with the Snippet here (works OK) and the Snippet on my server or at w3Schools.com on the other hand (does not work)?

**How can I avoid the form validation?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" name="custom">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label required" for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" required="required" name="custom[name]">
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-success" data-target="#toggleContainer" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">Toggle</button>
        <div id="toggleContainer" aria-expanded="true" style="">   
            1</br>
            2</br>
            3</br>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to set a `type` attribute (`type="button"`) to the button. By default it works as a submit button for the form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add button attribute `type="button"` If you are **not specifying** by default it will take as `type="submit"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" name="custom">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label required" for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" required="required" name="custom[name]">
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#toggleContainer" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">Toggle</button>
        <div id="toggleContainer" aria-expanded="true" style="">   
            1</br>
            2</br>
            3</br>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```